# Strugling with the proof of Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the given theorem and proof:

Corollary 3.11 (Rouchés theorem)

> Let $U$ be a domain and $\gamma$ a closed curve which bounds a domain in $U$ (the key case is when $U$ is simply connected and
> $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve). Let $f, g$ be holomorphic on $U$,
> and suppose $|f|>|g|$ for all $z \in \operatorname{image}(\gamma)$.
> Then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeroes in the domain bound
> by $\gamma$, when counted with multiplicity.

Proof:

> If $|f|>|g|$ on $\gamma$, then $f$ and $f+g$ cannot have zeroes on the curve $\gamma$. We let
> $$
>      h(z)=\frac{f(z)+g(z)}{f(z)}=1+\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}
>      $$
> This is a natural thing to consider, since zeroes of $f+g$ is zeroes of $h$, while poles of $h$ are zeroes of $f$. Note that by
> assumption, for all $z \in \gamma$, we have
> $$
>      h(z) \in B(1,1) \subseteq\{z: \operatorname{Re} z>0\}
>      $$
> Therefore $h \circ \gamma$ is a closed curve in the half-plane $\{z: \operatorname{Re} z>0\}$. So $I(h \circ \gamma ; 0)=0$. Then by
> the argument principle, $h$ must have the same number of zeros as
> poles in $D$, when counted with multiplicity (note that the winding
> numbers are all +1 ).
> Thus, as the zeroes of $h$ are the zeroes of $f+g$, and the poles of $h$ are the zeros of $f$, the result follows.

**My problem:** I am struggling to understand how this proof deals with the case when $f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$ have the same zero. I know that the result can be one of three things

- a pole
- a removable singularity with value zero
- a removable singularity with value non-zero

I do not see how the argument deals with this, and moreover, I can seem to prove for my self that the result is true if this case were to be allowed.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the number of zeros of $h$ minus the number of poles of $h$, counted with multiplicity. The argument principle tells us that $D = 0$.

Assume that $z_0$ is an $p$-fold zero of $f+g$, and an $q$-fold zero of $f$.

- If $p > q$ then $h = (f+g)/f$ has a $p-q$-fold zero at $z_0$.
- If $p = q$ then $h$ has a removable zero at $z_0$ with $h(z_0) \ne 0$.
- If $p < q$ then $h$ has a $q-p$-fold pole at $z_0$.

So in any case, the contribution of $z_0$ to $D$ is $p-q$.

Therefore a $p$-fold zero of $f+g$ contributes $p$ to $D$ and a $q$-fold zero of $f$ contributes $-q$ to $D$, no matter if that zeros are shared between $f+g$ and $f$ or not.

It follows that $D$ is equal to total number of zeros of $f+g$ (counted with multiplicity) minus the total number of zeros of $g$. Since $D= 0$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: I understand now thank you! Just a question, is this something that is typically not mentioned in Rouche's Theorem or is it just absent from the proof that I was given?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: I cannot tell how it is “typically done” and I do not have a complex analysis textbook with me right now. IMO it is better to say that “# zeros of h - # poles of h is zero” instead of “# zeros of h = # poles of h.” The case that zeros of $f+g$ and $f$ occur at the same place *might* be left as an “exercise to the reader” :)